# Finding the Shortest Distance from Point to Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I am trying to find the shortest distance from the point $(3,0,-8)$ to the plane $x+y+z = 8$ and I keep getting the same incorrect solution. First, I found the equation fo the distance to be: $d=\sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y^2) + (z+8)^2}$. Then I found the critical points of $d^2$. The critical point is $(\frac{14}{3}, \frac{5}{3})$. The minimum distance must be at this critical point so I substituted these values into the equation for distance, with $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$: $d=\sqrt{((\frac{14}{3})-3)^2 + (\frac{5}{3}^2) + (16-\frac{14}{3} - \frac{5}{3})^2}.$ This yields $3\sqrt{11}$, which is not the correct answer. Could someone help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: When you replace $z$ with $8-x-y$, you're dropping the $+8$ which is under your first radical; the second radical should have $16-x-y$ under it.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, but now I am getting 3sqrt(11) -- which still is not the correct solution I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: How did you get $\left(\frac{14}{3}, \frac{5}{3}\right)$ because it isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to minimize $d=\sqrt{(x−3)^2+y^2+(z+8)^2}$ subject to $x+y+z = 8$. This is equivalent to minimizing 
$$
(x−3)^2+y^2+(z+8)^2
$$
s.t.
$$
x+y+z=8
$$
because the new function is a strictly monotonic transformation of the original function. If you make the relevant substitution $z=8-x-y$ your FOC's would look like
$$
2(x-3) - 2(16-x-y) = 0
$$
and
$$
2y - 2(16-x-y) = 0
$$
implying that 
$$
x = y+3.
$$
It should be straightforward from here onwards.

note: thanks Carl below for suggesting edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an answer like Mike's, but just to show a different approach, my instinct is to just use vector operations.

A normal vector to plane $x+y+z=8$ is available from the coefficients which gives $\mathbf{n}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ or the unit normal $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}$.  Given a point $\mathbf{q}$ on the plane, the distance from a point $\mathbf{p}$ to the plane is given by
$$
\left|(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q})\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \right|
$$
or for your example
$$
\left| \left( \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ -8 \end{bmatrix} 
-\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\8 \end{bmatrix} \right) \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}\right| = \frac{13}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
where I arbitrarily chose $\mathbf{q}$ to be the point (0,0,8) on the plane.

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: Hi @CarlHeckman, I believe it in fact does solve the original problem.  It finds the shortest distance from the given point to the given plane.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: You need to find $q$ before you can use your formula. As you pointed out, you chose $q$ arbitrarily.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Yes you need a $\mathbf{q}$, but it can be any point on the plane.  I wouldn't say you need to "find" it, just pick one.  You can use $(4,4,0)$ or $6,2,0$, etc, they wall work.  So I'm still confused about how I didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$d^2 = (x−3)^2+y^2+(16-x-y)^2$

\begin{align}
    \dfrac{\partial d^2}{\partial x} &= 0 \\
    2(x-3) -2(16 - x - y) &= 0 \\
    x - 3 - 16 + x + y &= 0 \\
    2x + y = 19 \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \dfrac{\partial d^2}{\partial y} &= 0 \\
    2y - 2(16-x-y) &= 0 \\
    y - 16 + x + y &= 0 \\
    x+ 2y &= 16 \\
\end{align}

$$(x,y,z) = \left(\dfrac{22}{3}, \dfrac{13}{3} , -\dfrac{11}{3} \right)$$

\begin{align}
    d^2 &= (x−3)^2+y^2+(16-x-y)^2 \\
    d^2 &= \dfrac{169}{9} +  \dfrac{169}{9} + \dfrac{169}{9}\\
    d &= \dfrac{13}{\sqrt 3}
\end{align}