# I am trying to find the shortest distance from the point $(3,0,-2)$ to the plane $x+y+z = 2$ and I keep getting the same incorrect solution.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

[image]

Comment: not $(x+y-2+2)^2$  It should be  $(2-x-y+2)^2$

Comment: Thank you for including your work.  With a little more rep, you can upload images, As you ask more questions here, you can begin to practice formatting math, like @Soheil has done in their comment. See, e.g., [The MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I changed the title to match your picture.

Comment: As a sanity check, the shortest distance from $(3,0,-2)$ to the plane $x+y+z=2$ is obtained by moving in the normal direction $(1,1,1)$, so $(x,y,z)=(3+t,0+t,-2+t)$ for some $t$, with $1+3t=2$, so $t=1/3$, yielding $(x,y,z)=(10/3,1/3,-5/3)$.

Comment: Hmm, the original title matched the first sentence of [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676517/finding-the-shortest-distance-from-point-to-plane).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$d=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}},$$
where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ are the coordinates of the point, and $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ is the equation of the plane

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to find the distance from the poinnt $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to the plane $\Pi$ with equation  $$(1) \text { } \text { } \text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { } ax+by+cz+d=0.$$ First drop a perpendicular $L$ from the point $P_1$ to the plane $\Pi.$ The normal vector to the plane $\Pi$ is $[a,b,c],$ so parametric equations of $L$ are $$(2) \text { } \text { } \text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }\text { }x=x_1+at,y=y_1+bt,z=z_1+ct.$$ Substitute these expressions for $x,y \text { and }z$ into (1) and solve for $t$ in terms of $a,b,c \text { and }d. $ Substitute this value of $t$ into the expressions in (2) for $x,y \text { and }z$ to give $$x_*=x_1+at,y_*=y_1+bt,z_*=z_1+ct.$$ The line $L$ intersects the plane $\Pi$  in the point $P_*(x_*,y_*,z_*)$ , which is the foot of the perpendicular dropped from the point $P_1$ to the plane $\Pi.$ The shortest distance from the point $P_1$ to the plane $\Pi$ is the distance between the points $P_1$ and $P_*.$